# Perl: forking an WSS connection results in closure of the socket when child exits (doesn't happen with WS)

Tags: perl, websocket

(Edited to provide a reduced test case as per comments below)

I'm facing an odd situation, where if I fork a "WSS" connection to send a message, the socket gets closed when the child exits. However, when I fork to process a "WS" connection, the connection remains open when the child exits.

- Server Details: Perl 5.26, Ubuntu 16
- Client Details: Perl 5.18, OSX

Server code:

```
use Net::WebSocket::Server;
use IO::Socket::SSL;

$SIG{CHLD}='IGNORE';

my $enable_ssl = 1; # If you make this one the problem reveals itself

# you need to point this to your own certs
my $ssl_cert_file =  "/etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain/fullchain.pem";
my $ssl_key_file =  "/etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain/privkey.pem";

# To show the problem, all I'm doing is I'm forking and sending current time
sub process {
    my $serv = shift;
    my $pid = fork();
    if ($pid == 0 ) {
        print ("fork start\n");
        $_->send_utf8(time) for $serv->connections;
        print ("fork end\n");
        exit 0;
    }
}

my $ssl_server;

if ($ssl_enable) {
$ssl_server = IO::Socket::SSL->new(
              Listen        => 10,
              LocalPort     => 9000,
              Proto         => 'tcp',
              Reuse     => 1,
              ReuseAddr     => 1,
              SSL_cert_file => $ssl_cert_file,
              SSL_key_file  => $ssl_key_file
            );
 }

Net::WebSocket::Server->new(
    listen => $enable_ssl? $ssl_server: 9000,
    tick_period=>5,
    on_tick=> sub {
        my ($serv) = @_;
        process($serv);
        #$_->send_utf8(time) for $serv->connections;
    },
 )->start;
```

Here is the client code:

```
my $client = AnyEvent::WebSocket::Client->new;

# replace with your server
$client->connect("wss://myserver:9000")->cb(sub {
  our $connection = eval { shift->recv };
  if($@) {
    print ("connection error");
    warn $@;
    return;
  }

  # recieve message from the websocket...
  $connection->on(each_message => sub {
    my($connection, $message) = @_;
    my $msg = $message->body;
    print ("GOT $msg\n");
  });


});

AnyEvent->condvar->recv;
```

**Expected behavior**

The client will keep displaying timestamps

**Observed behavior**

The client gets the very first message and prints it.
When the server exits its fork, the client stops getting any more messages and the connection terminates

**How to make it work**

We have two options:

1. Don't fork in server. Send the message directly in process sub
2. Don't use SSL

Therefore, my conclusion is SSL+fork == problem.

Thoughts?

Comment: I'm not sure if I really understand your problem. First, since there does not seem to be any `exec` involved here attempts to do `close-on-exec` and similar make no sense. Then: a simple TCP socket will not be closed if the socket is on both parent and child and the child just exits. A SSL socket is different since the user space SSL state gets out of sync if the same socket is used in parent and child. I recommend that you actually create a __minimal__ program which shows the __full__ problem you face and where others can __reproduce__ it. The currently shown code does not help much.

Comment: Part of the problem might be some destructor running at exit, in which case `POSIX::_exit` could help. But the SSL state is probably going to kill you anyway.

Comment: ok, I'll write up a small client/server that exactly illustrates the problem.

Comment: I think @WumpusQ.Wumbley is on the right track as far as SSL state. Reworked and re-posted the Q

Comment: After working on the reduced test case and realizing the problem is in SSL+fork, it looks like there are many posts on the same subject. I'll look around for a workable solution where I can do what I need and share data between the parent and child (Looks like threads doesn't share data by default...)

Comment: I've recently seen another question about TLS and fork, but I can't find it now. The main answer is to put one process in charge of all the TLS sockets and have all the other processes feed it with pipes. But an alternative Linux-only answer is to use [kernel-mode TLS](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/Documentation/networking/tls.txt)

Comment: I would keep the socket in the main process and run the child code in a "real" subprocess and forward the output in the main process. Unfortunately, all the AnyEvent::(Sub)Process modules themselves fork(), so you will need to roll your own there...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Therefore, my conclusion is SSL+fork == problem.

Yes, the problem is first doing the SSL handshake and then forking. This way a user space SSL state will be created in the parent and with the fork duplicated in the child and these two SSL states get out of sync on the first SSL data send or received. This means it is not possible to deal with the same SSL socket from two processes.

If it is really necessary that both parent and child process use the same SSL connection to the peer than the child must use the parent as a "proxy", i.e. the child does not communicate directly with the SSL peer but the child needs to communicate in plain with the parent (for example by using a socketpair) which then can forward the communication to the SSL peer. This way the SSL state is only maintained in the parent process.

But given that only a single message should be handled at a time for a single connection it might be possible instead to not fork for a single tick but fork a child for each connection which handles then all messages in this connection. In this case the SSL handshake can be done in full in the child by listening in the parent to a TCP and not SSL socket, forking `on_connect` and then upgrading the connection to SSL in the client using `IO::Socket::start_SSL`. This would also have the advantage that the blocking SSL handshake (which involves several round trips and thus takes some time) would be done in the forked child and would not make the parent block.

Comment: Yup, what a pain. I really thought this would be simple. Thanks for asking me to work on a reduced test case - it got me to what the core problem was. Is there a reference I can read (not RFC, something easier) that tells me what really is the problem with SSL states that makes this hard to do?

Comment: @user1361529: it has nothing to do with an RFC. It is simply that most implementations of SSL are done as user-space library and thus the SSL state (i.e. encryption keys, sequence counter...) is kept in user space process memory. And it is a property of fork that the process memory gets copied and thus parent and child end up with their own  versions of the SSL state which get independently updated. But there can only be a single valid SSL state for a specific SSL connection, i.e. either in parent or in child.

Comment: Ah perfect explanation. Thanks.